# Java: generic enum in method parameter

Tags: java, generics, parameters, enums

Correspondig the following question:

[Java: Enum parameter in method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142420/java-enum-parameter-in-method)

I would like to know, how can I format the code to require enums generically.

Foo.java

```
public enum Foo { 
    a(1), b(2);
}
```

Bar.java

```
public class Bar {
    public Bar(generic enum);
}
```

Later on I'll have more enum classes like "foo", but you can still create bar containing any kind of enum class. I have "jdk1.6.0_20" by the way...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

See the methods in [EnumSet](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) for reference, e.g.

```
public static <E extends Enum<E>> EnumSet<E> of(E e)
```

(This method returns an EnumSet with one element from a given Enum element e)

So the generic bounds you need are: `<E extends Enum<E>>`

---

Actually, you will probably make `Bar` itself generic:

```
public class Bar<E extends Enum<E>> {

    private final E item;

    public E getItem(){
        return item;
    }

    public Bar(final E item){
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

You may also add a factory method like `from`, `with` etc.

```
public static <E2 extends Enum<E2>> Bar<E2> with(E2 item){
    return new Bar<E2>(item);
}
```

That way, in client code you only have to write the generic signature once:

```
// e.g. this simple version
Bar<MyEnum> bar = Bar.with(MyEnum.SOME_INSTANCE);
// instead of the more verbose version:
Bar<MyEnum> bar = new Bar<MyEnum>(MyEnum.SOME_INSTANCE);
```

**Reference:**

- [Java Tutorial - Learning the Java Language](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java)

  - [Classes and Objects > Enum Types](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)
  - [Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Comment: Thank you for that example, as nonsensical as the syntax is - which I am reading as "PLACEHOLDER extends Enum of PLACEHOLDER" (vs just "PLACEHOLDER extends SuperType" for non-enums)

Answer (score 18):

You can also do it this way:

```
public class Bar {
    public Bar(Enum<?> e){}
}
```

Every enumeration extends Enum. Then you can use this if you need the enum constants:

```
e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()
```

Comment: While this isn't using generics like OP asked, this answer will likely provide a simple solution to many people's problems without needing a generic to begin with!

Answer (score 10):

```
public class bar {
    public <E extends Enum<E>> void bar(E enumObject);
}
```

The `bar` method can now receive any kind of enum.